# Any way of getting vector of probabilities for each response with Naive Bayes in R?

Tags: r, naive-bayes, e1071

I'm currently using `naiveBayes` from `{e1071}`. My response is simply a prediction based on my independent variables. Is there a way to get the probability for each possible prediction as a response with naiveBayes? So if I was trying to predict the outcome of a race, the predicted results would look like this :

```
Name    position  prob
Tom          1    0.1
Tom          2    0.2
Tom          3    0.7
Jim          1    0.2
Jim          2    0.5
Jim          3    0.3
Elizabeth    1    0.8
Elizabeth    2    0.1
Elizabeth    3    0.1
```

As opposed to just

```
Name        position
Tom            3
Jim            2
Elizabeth      1
```

If this is not possible with Naive Bayes, are there any other standard models that would support this? Like a Random Forest for instance? I would appreciate any guidance/literature on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `type = "raw"` in the predict object.

```r
require(e1071)

fitted = naiveBayes(Species~., data = iris)
pred = predict(fitted, iris, "raw")
pred
```

Comment: Thank you @Firebug. Just a few follow up questions. What other values can be given to the `type` argument? I couldn't find much here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html. Also will the prediction always be given with the responses as features and probabilities as observations? (in which case I would just have to pivot it right?). Thanks again

Comment: @jgozal the way R documentation is structured you should actually look at the packages in question, so look for `naiveBayes` in the [e1071 manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf). The only types really are `classes` and `raw`. And yeah, all R predict functions I know will output predicted probabilities in that format.

Comment: ah interesting. I wasn't aware e1071 and R packages in general could introduce arguments into `stats` functions. Thank you!